# Few questions about sharepoint restful api

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Few questions about sharepoint restful API for document library

1. There is no single restful call to retrieve items of a specific view, right?
2. Now I called /fields to get all fields that are FieldTypeKind==20 (User), then I call /ViewFields to construct the query with expanding, finally call /items to get items. Is it correct?
3. calling /items can get all fields that I can saw on doclib web part, but there is no URL for files. Calling /files have no field I can use to match the items from /items, how to fix it?

Thanks
From Peter

Comment: Thank you all, i think i had a big mistake about learning sharepoint restful api. I found out it is base on oData and oData should provide the ability to link up different resources, in my case, it should has a way to link up items and files, rather than we call every single APIs and combine the data ourselves. I will do some research on it. Thank you for you time.

Comment: @PeterCheung Please don't forget to upvote the helpful answer and Mark the correct one from the below answers Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following are applicable to both list/library as appropriate

1. NO RESTFull api available to get items view based.
2. Yes, Always column which holder more or collection of metadata I can be accessed using `$select` and `$expand` 
   https://webapplication.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Issues')/items?$filter=ID eq 1&$select=Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Editor/Title

Check [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35796.sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-for-selecting-filtering-sorting-and-pagination-in-sharepoint-list.aspx) for MSDN documentation.

3. `$select` and `$expand` would work for document libraries as well. However, there is a slight difference while calling API for doc libs like below

```
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folderRelativeUrl')?$expand=Folders,Files
```

(or)

```
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folderRelativeUrl')?$expand=Files,Folders/Files,Folders/Folders/Files
```

Refer [here](http://sympmarc.com/2016/04/23/get-all-sharepoint-document-library-files-and-folders-at-a-serverrelativeurl-in-one-rest-call/) for more info.

Comment: i found something crazy:


/items/$filter=GUID eq (guid'efee39c7-ae90-434a-9174-9a9bd7411c74') which works great, but fail to filter the uniqueId



/items/$filter=UniqueId eq (guid’asdas9c7-1290-4123-9174-9a9bd7411c74') will return empty json. Althought i can't filter the uniqueId, but i can select it

Comment: What is the datatype of GUID column? If it is a string compare like string without typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

1.We can get list item of a list view using REST API + CAML Query.

**/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocumentLibrary')/getitems**

Check the article below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884647/using-rest-to-fetch-sharepoint-view-items

2.To get user field from list items, we can use like this:

**/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocumentLibrary')/items?$select=Users/Title&$expand=Users/Id**

More information: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx

3.To get files url, we can use this:

**/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocumentLibrary')/items?$select=FileRef**